Pip doesn't work inside virtual environment (Ubuntu)
I'm using WSL Ubuntu, trying to install Django on a virtual environment, however I have encountered a problem. Whenever I try to install something using pip inside a venv, I get the following probkem:
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/django/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/django/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==5.0.4 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Django==5.0.4
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.

I have seemingly tried every solution under the sun but I still can't get it to work. I'm running python 3.11.
I've tried reinstalling pip in the venv, but most methods of doing that requires to use pip itself, which still doesn't work. I've tried creating a new venv, same issue still arises. I've attempted more solutions but I've been going at this for a while now so I've forgotten most of them.

Does global (without virtual environments) pip work in WLS?

Pip works as expected outside of the venv, yes. It's only broken inside of a venv.

What's the output of python -c 'help("modules")'?  And python -c 'import ssl'?
